# Reverse for 'contents-occasion-step-1' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['myapp/create/step-1/(?P<current_object_id>\\d+)$']

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my django app I am trying to **redirect** to a view after user submits the form

**Error which I am getting**

```
Reverse for 'contents-occasion-step-1' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['myapp/create/step-1/(?P<current_object_id>\\d+)$']
```

**The function from which I am redirecting view**

```
def create_object(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DataBase(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.save(commit=False)
            form_data.created_by = request.user
            form_data.save()

            # save current object id in the session
            request.session['current_object_pk'] = form_data.pk

            manipulation_function(request, form_data)

            return redirect('contents-occasion-step-1', current_object_id = form_data.pk)
    else:
        form = DataBase()
    return render(request, 'my/create_object.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

**My urls.py**

```
url(r'myapp/create/step-1/(?P<current_object_id>\d+)$', views.contents_occasion_step_1, name='contents-occasion-step-1')
```

**My views.py**

```
def contents_occasion_step_1(request, current_object_id):
    """View
    """
    [My code below]

    return render(request, 'myapp/mytemplate.html', {
        'variable_for_template': request.session['variable_for_template']

    })
```

Comment: Any help will be appreciated since I am not getting if there is any syntactical error or not

Comment: `print(form_data,type(form_data))` before this line `return redirect('contents-occasion-step-1',........` to see the output

Comment: It is giving expected output `ABC <class 'myapp.models.DataBase'>`

Comment: it should work, what about `form_data.pk`?

Comment: Is the module which includes `urls.py` file in the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @Lemayzeur Even `form_data.pk` is giving correct output

Comment: @DenizKaplan Yes it is.

Comment: so try it that way `return redirect('contents-occasion-step-1',form_data.pk)` or maybe it's not in this `redirect` that you got the issue

Comment: I am still getting same error.I am basically not getting if I am having any syntax error or not

Comment: What is your Django version? There was a usage of redirect as `return redirect('contents-occasion-step-1', args=(form_data.pk,))` maybe you can try this.

Comment: 1.11 is what I am using